# Jenkins LDAP Authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jenkins

We use LDAP authentication with Jenkins on Windows via [Active Directory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin). After running for a while (sometimes for weeks, sometimes just for a day or so) the authentication stops working - when trying to log in it just hangs there. Only restarting Jenkins fixes it. The log is 'clean'.

Jenkins v1.458 (but it happened with previous versions, too). Active Directory plugin v1.26. Any ideas?

Comment: We use the same plugin and setup, but I have not seen the same issue. Have you filled in all the information (Site, etc) or are there some blanks? I remember before I put in the Site information, it used to take a bit to log in.

Comment: We did not put in any information - it just works. I suspect (although I am by no means sure) that there is a resource leak somewhere.

Comment: What OS is your Master Server?

Comment: @Sagar, WinXP 2002, SP3. Runs on a virtual machine.

Comment: Can you add the domain controller to the configuration? I would assume that the plugin would/should be able to pull that information directly from Windows, but that may be what is your problem.

Comment: @Sagar, I have a rather conclusive proof that the problem is Jenkins scalability, not LDAP: first one is unable to login, and then after a while you can't even connect anonymously. The number of threads shoots to almost 300. I do appreciate your ideas. In a couple of days I'll start working on solving that problem - I'm currently thinking of running Jenkins in a different servlet container.

Comment: I experience similar issues. I don't know the specs of the A/D server at this company (outside of my control), but sometimes I see the connection to the port  3268  is refused, and usually restarting Jenkins does not help: I must restart the OS.